# How to kill the oldest longest running instance of a process in bash

Tags: linux, bash

it usually the case that a process has been started twice.

I would like to kill the one that is oldest. How would I go about doing that in a one liner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with

```
pkill -o fooprocess
```

and can be inspected with

```
pgrep -ol fooprocess
```

Comment: @4ae1e1 Yeap, the autocorrect but, haven't added Linux commands to standard English vocabulary yet! Thanks for pointing it out :)